# Elisp help. Why does the following snippet fail?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to write a little script that notifies me when someone talks to me in erc. So I need to write a funcion that recieves what I presume are two strings, nick and msg so I can hook it. But my test function fails. I have tested growl-notify and the format s-expresions and they work fine but I cant get test to work. I have no idea why is it failing. Any pointers?

```
(defun growl-notify (&key message)
  "Use growl for notifications"
  (start-process "growlnotify" "growlnotifications" "growlnotify" "-m " message))

(defun test (nick msg)
  (growlnotify :message (format "%s: %s" nick msg)))

(test "Ppop" "something")
```

It gives the following backtrack, hope it helps.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function growlnotify)
  (growlnotify :message (format "%s: %s" nick msg))
  test("oi" "poi")
  eval((test "oi" "poi") nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (&key message) "Use growl for notifications" (start-process "growlnotify" "growlnotifications" "growlnotify" "-m " message)) 3))
```

Comment: s/Pop/oi/ and s/something/poi/

Comment: You called the function `growl-notify` but tried to invoke it as `growlnotify`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function growlnotify)`, which tells you that `growlnotify` isn't defined as a function.

If you look at your code, you'll see that you defined it like this: `(defun growl-notify (&key message)`, which defines a function called `growl-notify`. A simple typo.